# UWP Image sometimes not visible until after page resize

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I've got a pretty standard UWP xaml windows 10 app which contains several images on the main page about 50 i'd say.

I've defined the images in the normal way using the Image xaml tag and specifying the source property of the image to reference items in my apps Assets folder,

```
<Image Source="Assets/Image1.png"/>
```

I'd say 75%-80% of the time my app launches fine and all the images are visible in the right spots and at the right size etc... However on occasion i launch the app and a few images are not visible. Typically this is between 1-3 images. As soon as i resize the app or trigger an event that changes the image source the missing images are displayed.

Also the images have a Tapped event handler on them. When the image is not visible if you click the spot where the image is meant to be, the tapped handler gets invoked.

I'm at a bit of a loss to figure out what might be causing this issue. It's almost like the images are not loading in time or the GUI is not receiving a page refresh event after the image has loaded. Like i said resizing the app fixes the problem.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem usually happens when the system is low on memory so it doesn't load some images to lower the load. Loading 50 images, especially if they are large probably will cause such problem.

Setting `CacheMode` of your images to `"BitmapCache"` might help (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.bitmapcache?view=netframework-4.7.1#Remarks) - for WPF, but more detailed than UWP documentation). Otherwise I recommend making sure your images are not larger than necessary, because that would put unwanted stress on the machine.

In addition, you can use `DecodePixelWidth` and `DecodePixelHeight` properties to specify at what size should the images be loaded. This can be useful when you are for example displaying large photos in a thumbnail area. Setting `DecodePixel` properties will optimize the loading process for JPEG and PNG images so that the whole photo does not have to be loaded from the disk to the memory (see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.decodepixelwidth(v=vs.110).aspx)).

### Update

As per @JohnnyWestlake's suggestion you might want to look into the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-animations-and-media#optimize-image-resources) for more tips on image optimization. There are multiple useful tips that will help keep the memory footprint of the images as low as possible.

Comment: For UWP, manually setting DecodePixelHeight/Width is actually more of a bad idea if loading the image like above in XAML - as Windows will *automatically* decode it at the correct render sze in UWP. Not only that, if the image gets bigger at any point, it will automatically re-decode it at the new larger size. (Which is also why resizing the app causes the images to show in this case - it's re-decoded.)

Comment: Is it really the case :-O ? Do you have some link to that? I haven't come up with such mention in docs so far... And in case the width and height are not specified (stretch), I would think the decoding in the render size will not take place even then. Furthermore the OPs problem seems to point in the direction that the images are not being decoded efficiently

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake You are right, now I found it in the docs. It is possible the OP's scenario falls into one of the scenarios which the system cannot handle.

Comment: Using the option CaheMode="BitmapCache" fixed the problem.